# Java Compare 2 class objects

Tags: java, class

```
public class Glasses {
    String manufacturer;
    int price;
    String type;

    Glasses() {
    }

    Glasses(String prd, int pr) {
        manufacturer = prd;
        price = pr;
    }

    Glasses(String prd, int pr, String t) {
        manufacturer = prd;
        price = pr;
        type = t;
    }

    public static void Compare() {

    }
}
```

this is my code and i want to compare 2 glasses like i initialise an object glasses1(ray-ban,200,squared) and glasses2(china,100,rounded) and I want them to be compared. How can i do that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare for them?

Comment: Oh sorry, i want the function to type glasses 1 are from the manufactruer X, have the price Y, type Z, glasses 2 have manufacturere A etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite the method `equals(Object)` from class Object which returns the `boolean` if they are equal (you can define by yourself within this method what needs to be equal to define these instances as equal).

If you want the classes to be sortable for sorted map then you can implement the interface `Comparable` and the method `int compare(Object)`.

For instance:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Glasses other) {
    if (equals(other)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        //FIXME: when is a Glasses object smaller then an other Glasses object??
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    boolean equal = false;
    if (o instanceof Glasses) {
        Glasses other = (Glasses) o;
        equal = true;
        equal &= (manufacturer == null && other.manufacturer == null) || (manufacturer != null && manufacturer.equals(other.manufacturer));
        equal &= price == other.price;
        equal &= (type == null && other.type == null) || (type != null && type.equals(other.type));
    }
    return equal;
}
```

The implementation of the `compare` method is buggy because I don't know your logic when a Glasses object is 'smaller' or 'bigger' than an other Glasses object. Maybe you just need the `equals` method?

Addition:
The equals method can be made a little bit smaller but maybe a little bit harder to understand (depends on the fact if you know the handling of the "?"-operator):

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        boolean equal = false;
        if (o instanceof Glasses) {
            Glasses other = (Glasses) o;
            equal = true;
            equal &= manufacturer == null ? other.manufacturer == null : manufacturer.equals(other.manufacturer);
            equal &= price == other.price;
            equal &= type == null ? other.type == null : type.equals(other.type);
        }
        return equal;
    }
```

Comment: How can I write that in code? I am a beginner in Java

Comment: I've made a fault the first if-statement within equals has to check `instanceof Glasses` rather than `!= null` - sorry for that, I fixed it now.

Comment: What about hashcode? Once overriding equals, hashcode also needs to be overridden.